# Excel VBA: replace entire cell with value

Tags: vba, excel

Can you help me with loop that will go through cells A3:A50 and replace entire cell with a new value.

Reference below:

**[ita-IT]** to **IT**

**[jpn]** to **JA**

**[por-BR]** to **PTBR**

**[spa-ES]** to **ES**

etc.

Thanks for tips!

Comment: Seems like you need a for loop with a select case statement inside

Comment: Where is the code you are currently using?

Comment: why is `[por-BR]` becoming `PTBR`? without having any valid rules => *ctrl* + *H* or doing it manually may be faster...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub ReplaceValues()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim v() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    v = [{"ita-IT","IT";"jpn","JA";"por-BR","PTBR";"spa-ES","ES"}]


    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A50")

    For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
        r.Replace what:=v(i, 1), replacement:=v(i, 2), lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False
    Next i
End Sub
```

Edit:
There's no problem having 50 (or more) replacement pairs, but this would be much easier to manage by storing them in a table in the workbook, rather than listing them in a VBA array:

[image: Table of replacement values]

You can replace cell contents which have text before / after your lookup value by using wildcards. So combining those changes, your code now becomes:

```
Sub ReplaceValues2()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim v() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    v = Sheet1.ListObjects("tbReplacement").DataBodyRange

    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A50")

    For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
        r.Replace What:="*" & v(i, 1) & "*", Replacement:=v(i, 2), LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a limit for replacement pairs? I would need to have like 50 pairs maybe more. Also could you adjust the code to replace content of entire cell to _replacement_? e.g. randomtext[ita-IT]randomtext to IT

Comment: something like replace & delete everything else

Comment: I've edited my answer to accommodate your changed requirements

Comment: You probably won't get 50 pairs using the `v = [{"ita-IT","IT";"jpn","JA";"por-BR","PTBR";"spa-ES","ES"}]` style initialisation of the array - it's limited to 255 characters.  (But that is just another reason to store the table in the workbook.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach. If you get a lot of codes to replace it could look like spaghetti, and if there is a logic to the replacement, it would be nice to build in the logic, but it does what you asked, and is, I hope, readable.

```
Sub ReplaceStrings()
Dim result As String

For Each myCell In Range("A3:A50")
Select Case myCell.Value
  Case "[ita-IT]"
    result = "IT"
  Case "[jpn]"
    result = "JA"
  Case "[por-BR]"
    result = "PTBR"
  Case "[spa-ES]"
    result = "ES"
  Case Else
    result = myCell.Value
End Select
myCell.Value = result
Next myCell
End Sub
```

EDIT - To go with the original spirit but to meet the requirement of matching within the string, I replaced Case with an If Elseif series and used Like and wildcards to match. Note To match square brackets (assuming that was what you meant), I had to enclose them in square brackets. I also amended to reference the ActiveSheet to be safe, drawing on the other answer (which I am not criticizing, just showing another way to think about it).

```
Sub ReplaceStrings()
Dim result, s As String

For Each myCell In ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A50")
  s = myCell.Value
  If s Like ("*[[]ita-IT[]]*") Then
    result = "IT"
  ElseIf s Like "*[[]jpn[]]*" Then
    result = "JA"
  ElseIf s Like "*[[]por-BR[]]*" Then
    result = "PTBR"
  ElseIf s Like "*[[]spa-ES[]]*" Then
    result = "ES"
  Else
    result = s
End If
myCell.Value = result
Next myCell
End Sub
```

Comment: I was thinking more about a code that will check content of cell if there is a string I am looking for e.g. randomText[spa-ES]randomText > then replace content of entire cell with just ES

Comment: something like replace & delete everything else

Comment: done, but with 50 pairs this would get unreadable and annoying